# Regular Expression for string pattern

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions. I am looking for String which can have only characters 'SALT' which is prefixed by + or – sign.

I  am using `[(SALT){1}\+-]{8}` which is partially working. Not completely.

Total characters 8

Acceptable values

```
+S+A+L+T

+S-A-L+T

+T+L+A+S
```

These are the following values which are not acceptable.

No repeat of characters except +,- as a prefix only.

i.e

```
S+L+S+S ( Character is repeated in this )
S+++++ 
-------S
S-+S-+S
```

I would appreciate if anyone help me in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: "No repeat of characters" is a difficult requirement for a regex. It usually ends messy.

Comment: For a start, read the basic syntax manual again.`[(SALT)]` is a character class; it matches a single character which can be a literal `(` or `S` or `A` or ...

Comment: @Dukeling Well if there are only four characters, (s)he *could* do a negative lookahead / negative lookbehind for each of them. I agree though.

Comment: There are different regex flavors. If a Perl regular expression is acceptable, it makes this a lot easier (or, at least vaguely possible) than if you are restricted to traditional basic or extended regular expressions.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? It would probably be cleaner to check the length, strip the punctuation, sort the characters, and accept the result if they are exactly `ALST`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lookaheads to make sure all of your characters are there

```
^(?=.*S)(?=.*A)(?=.*L)(?=.*T)([+-][SALT]){4}$
```

Comment: ... provided your platform's regex support is Perl compatible.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why do you say that?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Because the first character must be a `+` or `-`, but it doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: The above answer works for me. thanks for overwhelming response for this question.

Answer (score 0):

A funny way (if the RE engine supports conditionnals and backreferences) :

```
^(?:[+-](?:(S(?(1)Z))|(A(?(2)Z))|(L(?(3)Z))|(T(?(4)Z)))){4}$
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
^(([+\-]([SALT]))(?!\2))+$
```

It uses negative lookahead assertion to prevent matching repeating ones.

Comment: This will match `SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS...`

Comment: `+S+S-S+S-S+S`. It won't prevent duplicates.

Comment: Still would allow `-S-A-A-A`.